# Problem with Power App (Loading data from power App to Excel)

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I am having a little difficulty uploading information into an *Excel* from *PowerApps*.

I created an app with 3 different data sources, 2 of them are *SharePoint Lists* where the information is uploading without any trouble. The 3rd one, an Excel table, is… not.

I am using the Excel in order to obtain a random name from "Colum1", the logic I found for it is:

```
Set(varRandom, Last( FirstN ( Filter(TableName, IsBlank(Column2)),1+RoundDown(Rand()*CountRows(TableName),0))).'Column1')
```

This works, giving a random name although I haven't figured how to take the user itself out of the equation. (Meaning, if I am using the app, I don't want to get my own name randomly selected)

From how it works, I want that when you touch a different button it submits the information that that random name has already been selected by someone, therefore, it can't be picked again. I tried `"SubmitForm(FormName)"` at first, but I believe I am missing information to tell Excel what to take from the data I am feeding it with and where to send it.

This means just uploading any data into Column3, which starts all blank so everyone can be randomly picked.

I am not a coder, so there's 89% chances I am just writing the functions wrong, but everything else on the app works fine: random selection, navigation between several screens, and the information being submitted to the 2 SharePoint lists.

In short: I need to

Remove the user using the app from the random selection
    Uploading any data into the third column so that one name can't be picked twice.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

To remove your name from being selected, first you need to let the app know what the name of the user is. You can ask the name of the user and store it in a variable.
Then, if I understand correctly, you write something down on the Column3 when a name is picked to let you know the name was already used and can't be used again. After you know the name of the user, you can write something down right away on the 'Column3' in the row corresponding to the user's name so it can't be picked anymore.
To help you with the Excel we'll need to know where you save your excel file.

Best regards